# Elevate Database - Script out all tables structure

Tags: database-design, table

Could some one please help/guide me how I can script out all the tables structure from a single database in **Elevate database.** (In SQL there is a way to do it but not sure how to do it in Elevate DB)

I am new to elevateDB and tried to find out at online portals but didn't get any useful information. Any help will be appreciable.

Note: This ElevateDB is on elevate software, just read online about this.
Elevate Software develops and markets the DBISAM and ElevateDB embedded database engines for database application developers, and the Elevate Web Builder development environment for web application developers.

Answer (score 0):

I am also new to ElevateDB and was facing a similar issue. I was able to get the table listing from the information schema.

```
select * from information.Tables;
```